# Is it possible to combine two labels for a new EDT

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2009

I created a new EDT whose title is "Customer order reference is mandatory".

Do I have to create a new label for it, or is there a way to combine "Customer order reference" (for which I have a label) and "is mandatory" (a label exists for that, too).

In the languages used in my configuration, the sentence "something is mandatory" is always ordered the same way, "something" first, and "is mandatory" second. That's why I hope to avoid creating new labels for this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No that is not possible on the EDT level - you may write custom code in forms / reports etc. which do the concatenation at runtime but IMHO that's not good practice.
Although you said that your languages have 'the same ordering' in this particular case, there is another risk of someone changing one label to something equivalent when considered in the sole context of that label itself but may conflict in conjunction with your initial label.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I feel that this is _the_ answer, however I wait a bit to see if someone can give more hope...
It may be a feature request for dynamics ax, to be able to produce composite messages according to templates. You are right that in this case, each label must be defined as usable in a composition, or not.